# Extending autocomplete for Go to insert function arguments

Tags: auto-complete-mode, programming, golang

`Autocomplete` for Go code (fantastically) suggests functions and helpfully shows the documentation for the function, e.g. arguments and return types.

[image: Example completion]

If I hit `tab`, the `DialHTTP` function is inserted.

My question: is it possible to insert a "template" of the argument call?  Since `autocomplete` shows the arguments, I would like to have this line inserted when I press `tab`:

`client, err := rpc.DialHTTP(network, address)`

Then I can replace the arguments with my arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install `yasnippet` and `ac-go-expand-arguments-into-snippets` is non-nil(Default is `t`) then argument snippet is expanded like following animation gif.

[image]

[company-mode](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode) provides such feature by itself, so you can use it without `yasnippet` by `company-mode`.

Comment: Hey thanks, worked perfectly (after I unborked my .emacs file...)

Comment: Hi @syohex, your emacs looks great! I'm trying to configure company-mode but it seems not work. Could you help me to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310330/can-i-use-emacs-with-company-mode-and-company-go-to-complete-gos-standard-libra? Also could you share your emacs configuration? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I commented github issues. And my company-go configuration is here(https://github.com/syohex/dot_files/blob/master/emacs/init/golang.el#L32)